# Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$election_name in view

Tags: laravel-5

In the controller, I store some data in an array.Then I want to send it in myelectionlist.blade.php

```
$my_election=[];
  $i=0; 
  foreach ($election_list as $election_list)
  {
          $my_election[$i]=DB::table('election')
                       ->where('id','=',$election_list->election_id)
                       ->get();
                       $i++;  
  }
 return view::make('myelectionlist')->with('election_list',$my_election);
```

I check with

```
  return $my_election
```

It works fine. But In myelectionlist.blade.php when I write

```
@for($i=0;$i<sizeof($election_list);$i++)                    
{{$election_list[$i]->election_name}}
@endfor
```

It does not work.

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$election_name
```

happens, How to solve the problem?

Comment: I solve the problem , if I use foreach loop instead of for loop it works , Do anyone give me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a combination of problems that I would fix in order to bring clarity to your code and explain to you the problem. First of all in your code you have:

```
foreach ($election_list as $election_list)
```

I'll rename the variable for you to see:

```
foreach ($foo as $foo)
```

So what this does is that inside the foreach loop you will get all the values one by one, like expected but every time you store it to the initial variable. And once you are done with the foreach or break out of it earlier the `$election_list` will have the last used value. It might have unexpected results if you're trying to use the same $election_list later again. So I would suggest to use a differet variable names perhaps like `$election_list as $election`

---

Next, it's a little bit unclear why you would track the $index of the new elements by yourself. Instead you could just push into the array like this:

```
$my_election[] = $newObj
```

---

**Actual error message:**

Now for the actual error message: `->get()` returns a Collection. So in the end you have an array full of Collections. So inside the for loop when you do `$election_list[$i]` - this will actually be a Collection object instead of the Model and thus the exception.

`->get()` will always get you the collection. For example with methods like `->first()` and find/findOrFail you would get a single model. These functions might also be more appropriate to use since we are requesting with and id anyway.

---

Additionally, if this question is not a simplified version of your code then what I think you should actually do inside the controller:

```
$my_election = DB::table('election')
    ->whereIn('id', $election_list->pluck('election_id')) // pluck will give all the id's
    ->get();
```

This way you have a Collection of models assigned to `$my_election`.

Comment: Brother, one more thing, What is the best way to get data from $my_election in blade.php ?

Comment: @AlimurRaziRana I would probably use foreach: `@foreach ($my_election as $election)`